# Group function not working on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I use the below query, but it shows some repeated items. So I use the `group` function, but it does not work.

```
SELECT p.productId, p.productName, p.catId, p.subCatId, p.productType,
       p.modelNo, p.picUrl, p.color, p.theme, p.productPrice, p.discountedPrice,
       p.quantity, p.details, p.mainPageDisplay, p.productPageDisplay,
       s.subCatId AS Expr1,
       s.subCatName, s.catId AS Expr2,
       s.rank, s.subCatName AS Expr3
FROM (products p INNER JOIN
      subCategories s ON p.catId = s.catId)
WHERE (p.color = 'red') group By p.productName
```

This query is working fine, but when I add `group by` then it's not working.

Comment: use ORDER BY clause GROUP BY FOR FUNCITONS MIN MAX etc

Comment: group by is work with only aggregate function or column by which its grouuped by..

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY`, all columns need to be either in the `GROUP BY` or contained in an aggregate - so you need to tell us/SQL Server what you want to do with each column that isn't `productName` - should we take the `MAX()` or `MIN()` value for each of those columns?

Comment: Can you give an example of repeated items, please?

Comment: it's showing 3 time Product name like pendrive then next value 100 in 3 time,after that it will pick nxt item ,laptop

Comment: So, as I said in my first comment - you need to tell us how to select an appropriate value for each column that *isn't* `productName`. You either need to define an aggregate, or, if you want to say "I want the first/last row's values", you need to tell us what ordering to use to define the first or last row.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495465/how-to-group-by-multiple-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever has explained above. The engine can only display a single row for each group. You're selecting other rows (that aren't part of GROUP BY clause). For each [ProductName] there can be different values for other columns. Hence the query fails.  Because those rows can't be determined to be displayed with your group name column.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a `GROUP BY` for selecting distinct rows, you need `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.productId, p.productName, p.catId, p.subCatId, p.productType,
       p.modelNo, p.picUrl, p.color, p.theme, p.productPrice, p.discountedPrice,
       p.quantity, p.details, p.mainPageDisplay, p.productPageDisplay,
       s.subCatId AS Expr1,
       s.subCatName, s.catId AS Expr2,
       s.rank, s.subCatName AS Expr3
FROM (products p INNER JOIN
      subCategories s ON p.catId = s.catId)
WHERE (p.color = 'red')
```

Comment: This means that you want distinct product, and something about subcategories which is group. Show us your data, and what your want.

Comment: these are column value repeated in 3 times                             24 KINGSTON (four pc. set) 2 13

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` statement doesn't contain any [aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp), so a `GROUP BY` statement is not appropriate.

Comment: yes that's error ,bt i use DISTINCT  also ,but showing same reult

Answer (score 1):

You need to use all the columns in the SELECT clause in GROUP BY Clause or otherwise use DISTINCT keyword after SELECT Keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL GROUP BY` aggregates (consolidates and calculates) column values into a single record value. `GROUP BY` requires a list of table columns on which to run the calculations.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) has an example to facilitate your understanding of the concept .