# How to group by multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I understand how `GROUP BY` works and I also understand why my query does not bring the results I am expecting. However, what would be the best way to eliminate duplicates in this case?

Let's say we have the following tables:

**City**

```
Id    Name
---------------------
1     Seattle
2     Los Angeles
3     San Francisco
```

**Person**

```
Id    Name            CityId
----------------------------
1     John Smith      1
2     Peter Taylor    1
3     Kate Elliot     1
4     Bruno Davis     2
5     Jack Brown      2
6     Bob Stewart     2
7     Tom Walker      3
8     Andrew Garcia   3
9     Kate Bauer      3
```

I want to retrieve a list of all cities and **just one** person that lives in each city.

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name as PersonName, p.Name as CityName
FROM City c
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.CityId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
```

**Result:**

```
Id    PersonName      CityName
----------------------------
1     John Smith      Seattle
1     Peter Taylor    Seattle
1     Kate Elliot     Seattle
2     Bruno Davis     Los Angeles
2     Jack Brown      Los Angeles
2     Bob Stewart     Los Angeles
3     Tom Walker      San Francisco
3     Andrew Garcia   San Francisco
3     Kate Bauer      San Francisco
```

Using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.Name as PersonName, p.Name as CityName
FROM City c
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.CityId = c.Id
```

**Same result.**

Just to be very clear. This is the expected result:

```
Id    PersonName      CityName
----------------------------
1     John Smith      Seattle
2     Bruno Davis     Los Angeles
3     Tom Walker      San Francisco
```

Would `subquery` be the only solution for this case?

Comment: you need only one record for each cityname ?

Comment: Correct. Ideally the first match from the Person table.

Comment: fist order by person-name than perform group-by. I wrote answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses a subquery to identify the "first match" from the `Person` table, which I have interpreted to mean the person with the lowest id value in each city group.

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.Name AS PersonName,
       t2.Name AS CityName
FROM Person t1
INNER JOIN City t2
    ON t1.CityId = t2.Id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CityId, MIN(Id) AS minId
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY CityId
) t3
    ON t1.CityId = t3.CityId AND t1.Id = t3.minID
```

There is probably also a way to do this with window functions.

Comment: From all suggested answers, this one has the best performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `Partition` By `City` and a `Sub-Query` should do the trick:

```
SELECT R.ID, R.PERSON_NAME, R.CITY_NAME FROM
(
    SELECT P.ID, P.NAME [PERSON_NAME], C.NAME [CITY_NAME],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ID ORDER BY P.ID) AS rn
    FROM Person P
    INNER JOIN CITY C
    ON P.CITYID = C.ID
) R
WHERE R.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
1       John Smith      Seattle
4       Bruno Davis     Los Angeles
7       Tom Walker      San Francisco
```

Comment: Although this query does return the expected results, it seems to be a bit slow.

Answer (score -1):

If above not working thant try **distinct**,

```
SELECT tbl.Id,
       tbl.PersonName,
       tbl.CityName
FROM
(
   SELECT c.Id, c.Name as PersonName, p.Name as CityName
   FROM City c
   INNER JOIN Person p ON p.CityId = c.Id
   ORDER BY c.Name, p.Name
) AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.PersonName
```

## edited

Here is query,

```
   SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.Name as PersonName, p.Name as CityName
   FROM City c
   INNER JOIN Person p ON p.CityId = c.Id
   ORDER BY c.Name, p.Name
```

Comment: This query won't work because you are selecting columns which are not specified in the `GROUP BY` statement (nor are they wrapped as parameters to aggregate functions).  This might have worked in MySQL though.

Comment: This query is returning the following error: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: than you can use distinct for this