# Selecting column from one table and count from another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
t1

id | name | include
-------------------
1  | foo  |  true
2  | bar  |  true
3  | bum  |  false

t2

id | some | table_1_id
-------------------------
1  | 42   |     1
2  | 43   |     1
3  | 42   |     2
4  | 44   |     1
5  | 44   |     3
```

Desired output:

```
name | count(some)
------------------
foo  | 3
bar  | 1
```

What I have currently from looking through other solutions here:

```
    SELECT      a.name, 
            COUNT(r.some)

FROM        t1 a
JOIN  t2 r on a.id=r.table_1_id
WHERE       a.include = 'true' 

GROUP BY    a.id,
            r.some;
```

but that seems to get me

```
name | count(r.some)
--------------------
foo  | 1
foo  | 1
bar  | 1
foo  | 1
```

I'm no sql expert (I can do simple queries) so I'm googling around as well but finding most of the solutions I find give me this result. I'm probably missing something really easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the second column from the  `group by` clause

```
SELECT      a.name, 
            COUNT(r.some)    
FROM        t1 a
JOIN  t2 r on a.id=r.table_1_id
WHERE       a.include = 'true' 
GROUP BY    a.name
```

Columns you want to use in an aggregate function like `sum()` or `count()` must be left out of the `group by` clause. Only put the columns in there you want to be unique outputted.

Comment: You are pulling the `a.name` column even though you are not grouping on it – would that compile in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

This is because **multiple column group requires the all column values to be same.**

See this link for more info., [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Actually in you case., if some are equal, table_1_id is not equal (And Vice versa). so grouping cannot occur. So all are displayed individually.

If the entries are like,

```
id | some | table_1_id
-------------------------
1  | 42   |     1
2  | 43   |     1
3  | 42   |     2
4  | 42   |     1
```

Then the output would have been.,

```
name | count
------------------
foo  | 2     (for 42)
foo  | 1     (for 43)
bar  | 1     (for 42)
```

Actually, if you want to group on 1 column as Juergen said, you could remove `r.some;` from groupby clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reading link, it makes more sense now. Wish I could give 2 check-marks :(