# Sum duplicate row values

Tags: sql, sum, duplicates, row, distinct

I'm trying to sum the values of rows two of which have duplicate values, the table I have is below:

Table name (Customers)

```
value   years   total
1           30    30
3           10    10
4           15    15
4           25    25
```

I would ideally like to finally have:

```
value  years   total
1      30      30
3      10      10
4      40      40
```

I've tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` to get rid of the duplicate row, also the join in the code below isn't necessary. Regardless both commands come to no avail. Here's my code too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  value,
  years,
  SUM(customer.years) AS total 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN language 
  ON customer.expert=language.l_id 
GROUP BY 
  expert, 
  years;
```

But that produces a copy of the first table, any input welcome. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why does `SELECT value, SUM(years), SUM(total) FROM customers GROUP BY value` not work?

Answer (score 27):

```
SELECT
   value,
   SUM(years) AS years,
   SUM(total) AS total
FROM customers
GROUP BY value;
```

You want the sum of the years and the sum of the total, per — *grouped by* — value.

Comment: And for those who want to group by multiple columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  value,
  years,
  SUM(customer.years) AS total FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
  value,
  years,
  customer.years AS total 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN language 
  ON customer.expert=language.l_id ) as TABLECUS
GROUP BY 
  expert, 
  years;
```