# Display only one row for values that appear multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple rows with the same name in this table, and I want to show only one of row of each. For example, with the following data:

```
| name | number |
+------+--------+
| exe  |   1    |
| exe  |   10   |
| exe  |   2    |
| bat  |   1    |
| exe  |   3    |
| bat  |   4    |
```

I would like to see the following results:

```
| name | number | 
+------+--------+
| exe  |  16    |
| bat  |  5     |
```

How can I achieve this result?

Duplicate response: My question only have 1 table, the JOIN ..ON command creates confusion in understanding, i think this simple question can help many guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum duplicate row values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369868/sum-duplicate-row-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  SELECT t.`name`, SUM(t.`number`) AS `number`
    FROM mytable t
   GROUP BY t.`name`
   ORDER BY `number` DESC
```

let the database return the result you want, rather than mucking with returning a bloatload of rows, and collapsing them on the client side. There's plenty of work for the client to do without doing what the database can do *way* more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregation function for this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(number) AS total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name;
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html) on aggregate functions, and here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19ccd8/1) example using your sample data.