# Total in Tables using Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have Data like This

> Data:

```
EMPID   MONTHNAME   ABSENTDAYS  DAYSWORKED  PRESENTDAYS PENALTY
10001   January     0           1           1           100
10001   January     0           1           1           100
10001   February    0           1           1           100
10001   February    0           1           1           100
10001   February    0           1           1           100
10001   March       0           1           1           100
10001   April       0           1           1           100
10001   April       0           1           1           100
```

This is my Code

> Code

```
        var html;
        var totalWorkedDays = 0;
        var totalAbsentDays = 0;
        var totalPresentDays = 0;
        var totalPenalty= 0;
        $(data).each(function (index, th) {
            if (th.MONTHNAME == 'January') {
                count = count + 1;
                totalWorkedDays = totalWorkedDays + parseFloat(th.DAYSWORKED);
                totalAbsentDays = totalAbsentDays + parseFloat(th.ABSENTDAYS);
                totalPresentDays = totalPresentDays + parseFloat(th.ABSENTDAYS);
                totalPenalty= totalPenalty+ parseFloat(th.RATE);
                html = '<td class="text-center" id=jan_' + th.SeqID + '>' + th.MONTHNAME + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalWorkedDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalAbsentDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalPresentDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalPenalty.toFixed(2) + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
            }
            if (th.MONTHNAME == 'February') {
                count = count + 1;
                totalWorkedDays = totalWorkedDays + parseFloat(th.DAYSWORKED);
                totalAbsentDays = totalAbsentDays + parseFloat(th.ABSENTDAYS);
                totalPresentDays = totalPresentDays + parseFloat(th.ABSENTDAYS);
                totalPenalty= totalPenalty+ parseFloat(th.RATE);
                html = '<td class="text-center" id=jan_' + th.SeqID + '>' + th.MONTHNAME + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalWorkedDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalAbsentDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalPresentDays + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-center">' + totalPenalty.toFixed(2) + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
            }
        });
        fa_table.append(html);
```

> Result:

```
Month     TotalAbsent    TotalWorked    TotalPresent    TotalPenalty
February  0              3              3               300.00
```

The month of January is not showing... 
i want to show all of the months dynamically with total below.

please help.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Hi Mami few suggestions
1. always use trim function while comparing two strings.
2. in your code "totalPresentDays = totalPresentDays + parseFloat(th.ABSENTDAYS);" i think it should be th.PRESENTDAYS

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `html` variable every time you put code in it, and you don't do anything with it until the `each()` iterator is finished. I would reexamine your `if` blocks, but the easiest fix is to move the last line of your code inside of that `each()` function (below the second `if` block).

Comment: when i move append inside each.. the column would not be sum up

Comment: @MamiSasazaki I'm honestly really confused about what you're asking, but I would suggest summing these numbers when you query your data instead of in the JavaScript. See this if you can use SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369868/sum-duplicate-row-values