# Mysql logic to count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have my table below:

```
| id   | version | type | test_id | value |
+------+---------+----------+---------+--------------------+
| 1235 |       0 |  600 |     111 | 2     |
| 1236 |       0 |  600 |     111 | 2     |
| 1237 |       0 |  600 |     111 | 2     |
| 1238 |       0 |  601 |     111 | 1     |
| 1239 |       0 |  602 |     111 | 1     |
| 1240 |       0 |  600 |     111 | 1     |
| 1241 |       0 |  601 |     111 | 1     |
```

I'm trying to retrieve the count dependents of the column value. Type 600 has three values of 2 and one value of 1. So I need the result 3 and 1. My co-worker told me to use distinct but I think I'm using wrong syntax?

```
(select distinct a.type from Answer a where type = 600)
  union 
(select distinct a.value from Answer a where type = 600) 
  union 
(select count(value) from Answer where type = 600 and value = 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by type and value.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98091/2)

```
 select type,
   value,
   count(*)
 from answer
 -- add your where clause
 group by type, value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select value, count(*) from a where type=600 group by value
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT type, value, COUNT(*)
FROM Answer
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: This answer could be more generic by not hard coding for value 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select type, count(value) 
from table
where type = 600
group by type
```

Wouldn't this be all you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TYPE,VALUE,COUNT(*) FROM Answer 
GROUP BY type,value
```

You can group based on multiple columns please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) for more details.

Comment: From each line, it gives me 1. Which the case I'm trying is get 3 and 1 value.

Comment: please include other necessary fields as well , i have edited the answer.