# Count records made by SUM query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML table populated by a query:

```
         $sql = "SELECT user_id , pag_title , SUM(pag_views) FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."' GROUP BY pag_title";
```

The output of the query can be (p.e.):

> title 1   35
>  title 2   25 . . .

How can i count the `35 + 25 + ...` ? I want to have a total sum.

Comment: Have you tried to use something like  $sql = "SELECT pag_title , SUM(pag_views) FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."' GROUP BY pag_title, page_views"; . See here further infos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: You want to calculate the sum in SQL or with javascript? If in Javascript, how does the output look?

Comment: No it's pure PHP, MYSQL. No Javascript here.

Comment: Did you try SELECT pag_title , SUM(pag_views) FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."' GROUP BY pag_title?

Comment: Yes I tried that but if i use the $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res) then i have the sum of the pag_title but not the pag_views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about having a PHP variable (called `$sum` for instance) and putting there your sum while iterating over the rows?

In alternative, you can put `WITH ROLLUP` at the end of you GROUP BY, so that you have an additional row in your result set with the sum you need.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I don't understand?

Comment: I guess you loop over `msqli_fetch_assoc` or something similar to print the result. So, when you do that, you can also sum the value you are displaying for pages to a `$sum` variable (initialized to 0). In that way, at the end you have the value you need.

Comment: Yes. It's working. I use $tot_pag_views = $row['SUM(pag_views)']; in my msqli_fetch_assoc. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(view) from(SELECT user_id , pag_title , SUM(pag_views) as view FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."' GROUP BY pag_title) as a";
```

Comment: this is really a silly thing. You get the same result with the query suggested by JamesBlond and your query is far slower than that one.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick. It selects the sum of all the views of a specific user:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(pag_views) FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."'";
```

UPDATE

Assuming you use PHP with mySQL, something like this should work:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(pag_views) FROM views WHERE user_id = '". $id ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "views: " . $row[0]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: And how can i get the value? If i use the mysql_num_rows it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer JamesBlond.