# Select sdudios, actors and amount of films produced in a certain studio

Tags: mysql

I continue experements with MySQL and have next. I need to select names of actors who starred in the films a certain studio. The selection includes the amount of films of the studio, which starred actor. The result is represented in the form of the table with the following columns: "Studio," "Actors", "Number of films". I have three table: actors, studios and films. actors and films have many-to-many, studios and film have many-to-many relationship. Actors and studios haven't relationship. So I can select studios, actors and films.

```
SELECT studios.title, CONCAT_WS(' ', actors.name, actors.surname), films.title 
FROM studios
JOIN studios_films ON studios.id = studios_films.studio_id
JOIN films ON films.id = studios_films.film_id
JOIN films_actors ON films.id = films_actors.film_id
JOIN actors ON actors.id = films_actors.actor_id
```

But how can I get not title of film but amount of films of the studio, which starred actor.
I think I have to use aggregate (GROUP BY) Function COUNT. But when I use it in my query

```
SELECT studios.title, CONCAT_WS(' ', actors.name, actors.surname), COUNT(films.id) 
FROM studios
JOIN studios_films ON studios.id = studios_films.studio_id
JOIN films ON films.id = studios_films.film_id
JOIN films_actors ON films.id = films_actors.film_id
JOIN actors ON actors.id = films_actors.actor_id
GROUP BY filmstudios.id
```

I don't get, what I want. Can You help me to create query?Thanks!

Comment: You are almost there. You want to count the films for every studio / actor combination, right?
That means, you have to add actors.id to your `GROUP BY` clause as well!

Comment: Its a pity but if use only `actors.is` you don't get wanted result(((

Comment: **add** `actors.id` to it. `studios.id` should still remain in there. See my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause with multiple columns. This way you can count the number of films for every studio / actor combination.

Your complete query would look like this:

```
SELECT studios.title, CONCAT_WS(' ', actors.name, actors.surname), COUNT(films.id) 
FROM studios
JOIN studios_films ON studios.id = studios_films.studio_id
JOIN films ON films.id = studios_films.film_id
JOIN films_actors ON films.id = films_actors.film_id
JOIN actors ON actors.id = films_actors.actor_id
GROUP BY studios.id, actors.id
```

You can read more about multiple columns in `GROUP BY` clauses here:

Question on SO: [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Tutorial: http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/Use-Multiple-Columns-in-GROUP-BY.html

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! Please, tell me. Is it possible to create this selection without using JOIN? I mean realize this task using another features of MySQL?

Comment: No, I don't think so. JOIN is the way to go here, when dealing with multiple tables.