# SQLQuery COUNT number of games per team

Tags: sql, select, count

I have 4 tables:

**Teams**

```
codTeam: 1
year: 1995
codYears: 1
codType: 1
name: FCP
points: 3

codTeam: 2
year: 1990
codYears: 1
codType: 1
name: SLB
points: 3

codTeam: 3
year: 1995
codYears: 3
codType: 2
name: BCP
points: 0
```

**Trainers** *(People who train a team)*

```
codTrainer: 1
name: Peter
street: Ghost street
cellphone: 252666337
birthdayDate: 1995-02-01
BI: 11111111
number: 121212121

codTrainer: 1
name: Pan
street: Ghost street Remade
cellphone: 253999666
birthdayDate: 1995-01-01
BI: 22222222
number: 212121212
```

**TeamsTrainers** *(In which team is someone training)*

```
codTeamTrainer: 1
codTeam: 1
codTrainer: 2
dataInicio: 1998-05-05

codTeamTrainer: 2
codTeam: 2
codTrainer: 2
dataInicio: 1998-06-07

codTeamTrainer: 3
codTeam: 2
codTrainer: 1
dataInicio: 1999-09-09
```

**Games**

```
codGame: 1
date: 2015-02-12 13:00:00
codTeamHome: 1
codTeamAgainst: 2
goalsHome: 3
goalsAgainst: 2
codTypeGame: 1

codGame: 2
date: 2015-02-12 15:00:00
codTeamHome: 2
codTeamAgainst: 1
goalsHome: 1
goalsAgainst: 2
codTypeGame: 3
```

So basically I want to:

**Get the table Games and show:**

Team Name | Trainer Name | Goals Home | Goals Against | Points | Ammout of Games from the Home Team

I have the following code for that in SQLQuery:

```
SELECT Teams.name, Trainers.name, Games.goalsHome,
       Games.goalsAgainst, Teams.points, COUNT(*)
FROM Teams, Trainers, Games, TeamsTrainers
WHERE Games.codTeamHome = Teams.codTeam AND 
      TeamsTrainers.codTeam = Teams.codTeam AND 
      TeamsTrainers.codTrainer = Trainers.codTrainer
GROUP BY Teams.name, Trainers.name, Games.goalsHome, 
         Games.goalsAgainst, Teams.points
```

(May have some errors as I translated)

Yet, the COUNT only shows 1 (Probably because on the WHERE it has "teamHome" so it only counts 1), yet, if it's because of that, how do I fix it?

**Result**:

```
FCP | Pan | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 (Count)
SLB | Peter | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 (Count)
SLB | Pan | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 (Count)
```

***It should be 2 for each one on the Count***

Any idea?

Comment: What's database: SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get wrong result is of wrong joing data type. You should use repsectivelly: **left, right or inner join** instead of joing data via using **where** clause. Your data model provides *1 to N* relationship, so you should use specific type of join.

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

**EDIT**

```
SELECT Te.name, Tr.name, Ga.goalsHome, Ga.goalsAgainst, Te.points,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Games 
        WHERE codTeamHome = Te.codTeam OR codTeamAgainst = Te.codTeam)
        AS CountOfGames
FROM TeamsTrainers AS Tt
    LEFT JOIN Teams AS Te ON Tt.codTeam = Te.codTeam
    LEFT JOIN Trainers AS Tr ON Tt.codTrainer = Tr.codTrainer
    LEFT JOIN Games AS Ga ON  Ga.codTeamHome = Te.codTeam
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ef13/5)

Comment: Don't really understand how to use it

Comment: Which part? What do you want to count?

Comment: The total amount of games a team has. (In this case, they both play twice, so the count should be 2, and not 1)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to create SQL Fiddle for you... Wait.

Comment: Added the select count without the rest and worked, as I don't really understand the rest as I never saw it in my life. Sorry for making you lose some time on that part, but it helped me in the end. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your WHERE clause by saying

```
[what you have] OR (Games.codTeamAgainst = Teams.codTeam AND ...)
```

However, this probably causes other problems because you probably care about whether a particular team scores the goals, not whether the home team scores the goals in games that team plays on either side.

You might not notice the other problems for a while because your GROUP BY clause is probably pretty far from what you want, and you might want to be selecting aggregate functions for a much simpler grouping.

Comment: That only spammed even more the games and didn't change the count. :/

Comment: @Ran: Do you understand what that GROUP BY condition does? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns. As I pointed out in my answer, you are probably making way too many groups. You are only pooling together games with exactly the same score, so you aren't grouping the game where the home team won 3-2 with the game where the home team lost 1-2. That's why you are getting a count of 1 game with a score of 3-2.