# SQL - return records with multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I am relatively new to using group by and aggregate functions in SQL, I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `artists` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ); 
CREATE TABLE `genres` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL); 
CREATE TABLE `songs` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL, `artist_id` INT NOT NULL ); 
CREATE TABLE `songs_genres` (`song_id` INT NOT NULL, `genre_id` INT NOT NULL );
```

I am looking to return artists that have songs in multiple genres. Any ideas most welcome!

I have this so far to link everything together but cant quite work out the grouping / aggregation required:

```
select a.name as name, g.name as genre 
from artists a inner join songs s on a.id = s.artist_id
inner join songs_genres sg on s.id = sg.song_id
inner join genres g on g.id = sg.genre_id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to specify which aggregate functions and for what you want to use !!? the things you described in function saying that you don't need using it

Comment: The syntax is clearly MySQL, so I'm removing the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. It will find how many genres have multiple artists:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.Name) AS "No. of Artists",
       g.Name AS "Genre"
FROM Artists a
INNER JOIN songs s on a.id = s.artist_id
INNER JOIN songs_genres sg on s.id = sg.song_id
INNER JOIN genres g on g.id= sg.genre_id
GROUP BY g.Name
```

This will give you the number of genres per artist:

```
SELECT COUNT(g.Name) AS "No. of Genres",
           a.Name AS "Artist"
FROM Artists a
INNER JOIN songs s on a.id = s.artist_id
INNER JOIN songs_genres sg on s.id = sg.song_id
INNER JOIN genres g on g.id= sg.genre_id
GROUP BY a.Name
```

Adding a `HAVING` clause will allow you to narrow your results to those Artists/Genres with more than any number:

```
SELECT COUNT(g.Name) AS "No. of Genres",
               a.Name AS "Artist"
    FROM Artists a
    INNER JOIN songs s on a.id = s.artist_id
    INNER JOIN songs_genres sg on s.id = sg.song_id
    INNER JOIN genres g on g.id= sg.genre_id
    GROUP BY a.Name
HAVING Count(g.Name) > 1 -- or 2, or 10. This will skip over single-genre artists
```

What you're doing in these queries is counting how many times a given value shows up when grouping by another value.

Comment: Thank you guys, Phoenix in particular, I have tweaked your code to get what I need.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(distinct g.id) AS "genres", a.name AS "artist"
    FROM artists a
    INNER JOIN songs s ON a.id = s.artist_id
    INNER JOIN songs_genres sg ON s.id = sg.song_id
    INNER JOIN genres g ON g.id= sg.genre_id
    GROUP BY a.name
    HAVING Count(distinct g.id) > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can check group by documentation http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp, bu I think you can do the following

```
    select a.name as name, g.name as genre 
    from artists a inner join songs s on a.id = s.artist_id
    inner join songs_genres sg on s.id = sg.song_id
    inner join genres g on g.id = sg.genre_id
    group by name, genre desc
```

I hope this helps, also you can check this threat [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)