# not getting proper output in Group by Clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have been trying the following query using **group by** and **inner join** clause in **asp.net**:

```
SELECT tblVendorItem.Name AS Product, 
       tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price AS Sale
FROM 
       tblEventService 
INNER JOIN tblEventItem ON 
       tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID 
INNER JOIN tblVendorItem ON 
       tblVendorItem.VendorItemID = tblEventItem.VendorItemID
WHERE        
       (tblEventService.VendorID = 2)
GROUP BY 
        tblVendorItem.Name, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
```

On executing this, what I get is:

[image]

What I really want is, Product should be not repeated and the total sales should come!

For eg: Mercedes 75

Can any one help me out?

I am attaching the database also:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `sum(tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price) AS Price` and remove group by clause in `tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price`

Comment: it's not working! @abhik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN tblEventItem ON 
   tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID 

GROUP BY 
    tblVendorItem.Name, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
```

In the group by clause, remove tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price. Hence your query should be changed in two places.
First, SUM(price*quantity) and second:

```
GROUP BY 
    tblVendorItem.Name
```

The reason is this:
Group By X means put all those with the same value for X in the one group.

Group By X, Y means put all those with the same values for both X and Y in the one group.

Group By X means put all those with the same value for X in the one group.

Group By X, Y, Z means put all those with the same values for both X ,Y and Z in the one group.
I hope this helps.[Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)
Kudos! :)

Comment: The underlined attributes are the foreign key and table are joined using primary key only! Moreover, using SUM makes no change in the output. @Sonia

Comment: Do each of these tables have primary keys?

Comment: By the way, My previous answers about primary key was wrong. I tested on my tables. Even if tables don't have any primary key, group by clause works. I hope that my answer solves your problem.

Comment: it worked! When I tried to remove any table from group by it shows error of aggregate function but don't know why it started working when price and quantity are removed. @Sonia

Comment: As I said in my answer, Read about how group clause works when you mention more than one columns. Check your database entries. You'll get it. :)