# return the last row that meets a condition in sql

Tags: sql, select, group-by, max

I have two tables:

**Meter**

```
ID         SerialNumber
=======================
1          ABC1
2          ABC2
3          ABC3
4          ABC4
5          ABC5
6          ABC6
```

**RegisterLevelInformation**

```
ID         MeterID    ReadValue    Consumption  PreviousReadDate    ReadType
============================================================================
1          1          250          250          1 jan 2015          EST
2          1          550          300          1 feb 2015          ACT
3          1          1000         450          1 apr 2015          EST
4          2          350          350          1 jan 2015          EST
5          2          850          500          1 feb 2015          ACT
6          2          1000         150          1 apr 2015          ACT
7          3          1500         1500         1 jan 2015          EST
8          3          2500         1000         1 mar 2015          EST
9          3          5000         2500         4 apr 2015          EST
10         4          250          250          1 jan 2015          EST
11         4          550          300          1 feb 2015          ACT
12         4          1000         450          1 apr 2015          EST
13         5          350          350          1 jan 2015          ACT
14         5          850          500          1 feb 2015          ACT
15         5          1000         150          1 apr 2015          ACT
16         6          1500         1500         1 jan 2015          EST
17         6          2500         1000         1 mar 2015          EST
18         6          5000         2500         4 apr 2015          EST
```

I am trying to group by meter serial and return the last actual read date for each of the meters but I am unsure as to how to accomplish this. Here is the sql I have thus far:

```
select a.SerialNumber, ReadTypeCode, MAX(PreviousReadDate) from Meter as a
left join RegisterLevelInformation as b on a.MeterID = b.MeterID
where ReadType = 'ACT'
group by a.SerialNumber,b.ReadTypeCode, PreviousReadDate
order by a.SerialNumber
```

I can't seem to get the `MAX` function to take effect in returning only the latest actual reading row and it returns all dates and the same meter serial is displayed several times.

If I use the following sql:

```
select a.SerialNumber, count(*) from Meter as a
left join RegisterLevelInformation as b on a.MeterID = b.MeterID
group by a.SerialNumber
order by a.SerialNumber
```

then each serial is shown only once. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's returning all of the read dates because you have included that column in your `GROUP BY` clause.  Take it out, and see what you get.

Comment: Does `PreviousReadDate` is date data type column?

Comment: Which `rdbms` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @PaulGriffin said in his comment you need to remove `PreviousReadDate` column from your `GROUP BY` clause.

**Why are you experiencing this behaviour?**

Basically the partition you have chosen - `(SerialNumber,ReadTypeCode,PreviousReadDate)` for each distinct pair of those values prints you `SerialNumber, ReadTypeCode, MAX(PreviousReadDate)`. Since you are applying a `MAX()` function to each row of the partition that includes this column you are simply using an aggregate function on one value - so the output of `MAX()` will be equal to the one without it.

**What you wanted to achieve**

Get `MAX` value of `PreviousReadDate` for every pair of  `(SerialNumber,ReadTypeCode)`. So this is what your `GROUP BY` clause should include.

```
select a.SerialNumber, ReadTypeCode, MAX(PreviousReadDate) from Meter as a
left join RegisterLevelInformation as b on a.MeterID = b.MeterID
where ReadType = 'ACT'
group by a.SerialNumber,b.ReadTypeCode
order by a.SerialNumber
```

Is the correct SQL query for what you want.

**Difference example**

```
ID         MeterID    ReadValue    Consumption  PreviousReadDate    ReadType
============================================================================
1          1          250          250          1 jan 2015          EST
2          1          550          300          1 feb 2015          ACT
3          1          1000         450          1 apr 2015          EST
```

Here if you apply the query with grouping by 3 columns you would get result:

```
SerialNumber | ReadTypeCode | PreviousReadDate
  ABC1       |    EST       | 1 jan 2015 -- which is MAX of 1 value (1 jan 2015)
  ABC1       |    ACT       | 1 feb 2015
  ABC1       |    EST       | 1 apr 2015
```

But instead when you only group by `SerialNumber,ReadTypeCode` it would yield result (considering the sample data that I posted):

```
SerialNumber | ReadTypeCode | PreviousReadDate
  ABC1       |    EST       | 1 apr 2015 -- which is MAX of 2 values (1 jan 2015, 1 apr 2015)
  ABC1       |    ACT       | 1 feb 2015 -- which is MAX of 1 value (because ReadTypeCode is different from the row above
```

**Explanation of your second query**

In this query - you are right indeed - each serial is shown only once.

```
select a.SerialNumber, count(*) from Meter as a
left join RegisterLevelInformation as b on a.MeterID = b.MeterID
group by a.SerialNumber
order by a.SerialNumber
```

But this query would produce you odd results you don't expect if you add grouping by more columns (which you have done in your first query - *try it yourself*).

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer it is greatly appreciated I now understand what the group by function actually does!!! :)  I have tried furthering this by declaring MAX(PreviousReadDate) as readdate and using this in a where function so I could check those who have had a read between today and 6 months ago

Comment: Glad I could help with basic understanding - the rest is yours to go :) You can also accept the answer if you feel like it's exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove PreviousReadDate from your Group By clause.
This is what your query should look like:

```
select a.SerialNumber, ReadTypeCode, MAX(PreviousReadDate) from Meter as a
left join RegisterLevelInformation as b on a.MeterID = b.MeterID
where ReadType = 'ACT'
group by a.SerialNumber,b.ReadTypeCode
order by a.SerialNumber
```

To understand how the group by clause works when you mention multiple columns, follow this link: [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

You will understand what was wrong with your query and why it returns all dates and the same meter serial is displayed several times.
Good luck!
Kudos! :)