# How to group by two dates to sum an quantity

Tags: sql-server

I have a `table` as below

```
   Art      PP No        ArtDate     ArtQty OPDate       OPQTY

   102844   1100023223   02-09-2015  0      31-08-2015      0
   102844   1100023766   03-11-2015  0      05-11-2015      1
   102844   1100023766   03-11-2015  1      05-11-2015      149
   102844   1100023766   03-11-2015  149    05-11-2015      1
```

I need to `group by` and expected answer

```
 Art    PP No       ArtDate         ArtQty  OPDate       OPQTY

102844  1100023223  02-09-2015      0       31-08-2015   0
102844  1100023766  03-11-2015      150     05-11-2015  151
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to use `GROUP BY [PP No],[ArtDate]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Art , PPNo  , ArtDate , SUM(ArtQty) ArtQty , OPDate, SUM(OPQTY) OPQTY
FROM
YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Art,PPNO, ArtDate, OPDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first group by in subquery and then get a result if you need all in above order, or the subquery will work for the sake of output you want.

```
   Select Art, PPNo, ArtDate, ArtQty, OPDate, OPQTY 
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT Art, PPNo, ArtDate, OPDate, SUM(OPQTY) AS OPQTY, SUM(ArtQty) as ArtQty FROM TABLENAME
    GROUP BY Art, PPNo, ArtDate, OPDate
    )
```