# multiple group in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

It gives me 11 results

```
select min(e.UserId), e.Value from Table 
where UserId = 1 and EventTypeId = 3 and Value is not null 
group by e.Value
```

But if I'll query that:

```
SELECT e.UserId, e.Value, count(UserId) as UserIdCount
  FROM [G3CR_Test].[dbo].[EventLog] as e
  where EventTypeId = 3 and Value is not null and UserId = 1
  group by e.UserId, e.Value
  order by e.UserId
```

It gives a result

```
UserId  Value   UserIdCount

1       X1             1
1       X2             1
1       X3             12
1       X4             1
1       X5             5
1       X6             1
1       X7             1
1       X8             1
1       X9             12
1       X10             1
1       X11             1
```

So instead of write directly 11 of UserIdCount it splits them.
I know why it works that way ([see link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns))

But I want to group them at first by Value and than UserId. How is that possible?

I want result to be

```
UserId  Value   UserIdCount

1       X            11
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is rather hard to decipher what you may be asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited

Comment: What is `X`? It is shown as a distinct value in the first result set, so what do you want to get in the second case?

Comment: @AlexanderMP It's ID number. It's no matter about question. There are many same X in db so I group them to get distincts.

Comment: Your second query seems sound.  Are all the values of `X` in your `Value` column not actually the same?  Like, would it be more accurate to describe them as `X1`, `X2`,...`X11`?  Your `GROUP BY` only has those two fields, so it's the only thing I can think of that would cause the results you're reporting.

Comment: `1       X            11` that is the result you want to get. What is `X` in this case?

Comment: @AlexanderMP X doesn't matters in that case. It must be grouped at first to not get same values and then I want count of them.

Comment: If I'll remove group of e.Value then it returns 37 of count (so they're not distinct values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a count of rows AFTER your initial query does the preliminary grouping, so we make your original query into a subquery, then do a count on that...

```
SELECT
    DerivedPreGrouped.UserId,
    COUNT(DerivedPreGrouped.UserIdCount) AS [Count]
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        e.UserId, 
        e.Value, 
        count(UserId) as UserIdCount
    FROM 
        [G3CR_Test].[dbo].[EventLog] as e
    where 
        EventTypeId = 3 
        and 
        Value is not null 
        and UserId = 1
    group by 
        e.UserId 
        , e.Value
    /*
    order by 
        e.UserId
    --order by invalid in subquery
    */
    ) DerivedPreGrouped
GROUP BY
    DerivedPreGrouped.UserId
ORDER BY
    DerivedPreGrouped.UserId
```

Comment: If I'll remove group of e.Value then it returns 37 of count (so they're not distinct values)