# SQL count not showing result properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a simple `select` query

```
select count(status_flag) STATUS_COUNT
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr
where to_user = 1279  and status_flag = 4
```

which displays results as

[image: Simple SELECT]

I have joined with `user_mst` table like below:

```
SELECT COUNT (a.status_flag) counts, a.mkey, a.to_user, b.email,
       b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name name
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
    LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey
WHERE a.to_user = '1279' AND a.status_flag = '4' 
group by a.mkey, a.to_user, b.email, b.first_name,b.last_name
```

which displays result as

[image: JOIN QUERY]

So my issue is

> why  the second query is showing two rows for the same `to_user` whose count is **2**.

I am using `sql-server-2005`

Comment: Because they belong in a different group since `mkey` is not equal.

Comment: @FelixPamittan:yes may be that might be the issue

Comment: So you need to remove `mkey` from your `GROUP BY`, if you want to combine and get the same `count` as previous query

Comment: @sonique: yes removed and checked. Need to confirm with other people whether removing mkey is not an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping on mkey also that's why its showing you two different counts.
Use below query may be it helps you.

```
SELECT COUNT (a.status_flag) counts,  a.to_user, b.email, b.first_name + ' ' + 
b.last_name name FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a LEFT JOIN user_mst b 
ON a.to_user = b.mkey WHERE a.to_user = '1279' AND a.status_flag = '4' 
Group by  a.to_user, b.email, b.first_name,b.last_name
```

Comment: hey sandeep, its working. let me confirm whether removing mkey wont make any issue.

Comment: If you have to use mkey then you can use its Max or MIN value also. What is your requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not understood how `group by` on multiple keys work just read [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) which will provide you information about it, and will definitely solve what problem is there in your SQL.

Moreover the problem you are getting two rows is because of column `mkey` which is different on both rows.

I am also unable to understand why, so many columns have been placed in `group by` as you have joined table on

`LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey`

so you know exactly how rows are joining, (user is mapped with respective user data only), so I think only `group by` should be on `a.to_user`.