# Getting Different ID Values in one table with DISTINCT query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[My table in the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mIpu.png)

As you can see i have a table contain several IDs including  Survey_survey ID and Store ID, i want to get all the **Store IDs** and their **Survey_surveyID**s without duplicates.

Here is what i have tried

```
$getSurvey = mysqli_query($dbConnection , "SELECT DISTINCT Survey_surveyId FROM maintable");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSurvey)) {

$getStoreIDS = mysqli_query($dbConnection , "SELECT DISTINCT Stores_storeID FROM maintable WHERE Survey_surveyId=".$row['Survey_surveyId']."");
```

Comment: don't do that. Unless you have a very explicit reason for doing so, anytime you have nested queries, and the "lower" query uses data from the "higher" one, you should rewrite them as a single `JOIN`ed query.

Comment: You should use GROUP BY in your query with two values:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Stores_storeID, Survey_surveyId FROM maintable

Comment: @NicolasP. Er, no.