# Group by two column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want group this table

```
column1|    date

A      |2016-07-01
A      |2016-07-01
A      |2016-07-02
C      |2016-07-01
C      |2016-07-02
```

and i need get the result something like this

```
column1 |   date
A       |2016-07-01
A       |2016-07-02
C       |2016-07-01
C       |2016-07-02
```

This is what i did to sort the table to get the result like above table

```
SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY column1 and date
```

but not working . How can i do that ?

Comment: You've seen the other threads on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1):

Based on your desired results ... It appears  that you are looking to get all distinct combinations of two columns

There are 2 ways to do that :

1. select distinct column1, date from table1
2. select column1, date from table1 group by column1, date

Comment: i missed the distinct . first one is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the result show in your question you should use

```
SELECT column1, `date`  FROM table1 GROUP BY  `date`
order by column1, `date`
```