# SQL- Top count(column1) w.r.t Distinct column2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns,

```
| User_id (INT) | CountryCode (VARCHAR) | channel_accessed (VARCHAR) |
```

There is no primary key over here, so repetition is possible for all columns.

I want to write a SQL query that returns Top countries name & there corresponding count w.r.t unique User_id

Tried following this [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) but this has not helped me much.

sample data :

```
| User_id (INT) | CountryCode (VARCHAR) | channel_accessed (VARCHAR) |
 1                  US                      ARY
 2                  CA                      ARY
 3                  CA                      MTV
 2                  CA                      HUMTV
 4                  US                      Tensports
 5                  US                      Star Sports
 2                  CA                      PTV
 2                  CA                      QTV
 2                  CA                      NATGEO
```

Expected Result : US, because it has more unique users.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySql

Comment: Add some sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select CountryCode
from yourtable
group by CountryCode
order by count(distinct User_id) desc
limit 1
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/301cbe/1)

Answer (score -1):

If the `channel_accessed` column doesn't matter then you could try

```
SELECT CountryCode, MAX(user_count)
FROM (SELECT CountryCode,
             COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) as user_count
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY CountryCode)
```

Comment: You can use an aggregate function on an aggregate function!