# how to use sql group by

Tags: c#, sql

```
select  EmbroiderAccountId, 
        EmbroiderReceivedDeliveryChallanId BuyerOrderProductId,
        EmbroiderDeliveryChallanNo, 
        EmbroiderName, 
        sum(Qty), 
        OrderNo, 
        Rate, 
        sum(Debit), 
        Credit, 
        EmbroiderReceivedChallanNo, 
        EmbroiderPaymentBillNo, 
        EmbroiderPaymentBillDate, 
        TransactionNaration
from dbo.EmbroiderAccount
group by EmbroiderReceivedChallanNo
```

Comment: Seriously !!! mention your input and output more clearly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to group by all columns used in select query except those with aggregate function:

```
SELECT EmbroiderAccountId
    ,EmbroiderReceivedDeliveryChallanId BuyerOrderProductId
    ,EmbroiderDeliveryChallanNo
    ,EmbroiderName
    ,sum(Qty)
    ,OrderNo
    ,Rate
    ,sum(Debit)
    ,Credit
    ,EmbroiderReceivedChallanNo
    ,EmbroiderPaymentBillNo
    ,EmbroiderPaymentBillDate
    ,TransactionNaration
FROM dbo.EmbroiderAccount
GROUP BY EmbroiderAccountId
    ,EmbroiderReceivedDeliveryChallanId 
    ,EmbroiderDeliveryChallanNo
    ,EmbroiderName
    ,OrderNo
    ,Rate
    ,Credit
    ,EmbroiderReceivedChallanNo
    ,EmbroiderPaymentBillNo
    ,EmbroiderPaymentBillDate
    ,TransactionNaration
```