# How to use sql GROUP BY clause on two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Mysql tables :

**station :**

[image]

**logger :**

[image]

**Using this sql query it's showing following result :**

```
$getStation = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT st.st_tbl_id, st.st_name, st.st_address, st.st_lat, st.st_long, st.created,
GROUP_CONCAT(lg.lg_name) AS lg_name 
FROM station AS st 
LEFT JOIN logger AS lg ON lg.lg_id = st.lg_id 
GROUP BY st.st_name, st.st_id, st.lg_id 
ORDER BY st.st_tbl_id DESC");
```

[image]

Here you can see station name is duplicate value but it's should be unique one. Like for this scenario it's should be Comilla and Dhaka

Comment: Your query and results doesn't match. Try to add the proper query and the actual result.

Comment: My query and the result is right. I checked it

Comment: The logger name is different for the same station name, that's why it's not grouped properly.If u don't want duplicate station name, remove the loggername from `select` and `group by`.

Comment: I want to show unique `st_name` with all `lg_name`

Comment: please provide sample data using sql format then it would be great and give you right solution within a short time.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran I got the issue, Thank You :)

Comment: @shibbirahmed The loggerName is different for all of them, remove it in select command

Comment: @javadaskari If i remove it how can show it ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed each person have 2 loggerNames, so you can't do this

Comment: well, there 3 tables. 1) station 2) logger 3) channel.. Each station can add multiple logger and each logger can add multiple channel.

Answer (score 0):

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421441/347565

In your case, those entries have different lg_id, so they won't be grouped together. I think you just change your query to only group by st.st_id and you'll get the results you want.

Comment: If I use only `st.st_id` then all duplicate `lg_name` is showing

Comment: Can you update your question with what you get if you only 'group by st.st_id'. I'm pretty sure you would get only one row per st_id...isn't that what you want?

Comment: If I use group by `st.st_id` then `st_name` is showing unique value but `lg_name` is showing duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$getStation = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT st.st_name, st.st_address, st.st_lat, st.st_long, st.created,
GROUP_CONCAT(lg.lg_name) AS lg_name 
FROM station AS st 
LEFT JOIN logger AS lg ON lg.lg_id = st.lg_id 
GROUP BY st.st_name,st.st_address,st.st_lat, st.st_long, st.created");
```

Comment: same result like mine.

Comment: Yes dude I did it

Comment: Your latest updated code is showing duplicate lg_name.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `table_id` from `order by`.. Updated it again.. let me know in case it gives any problem

Comment: Undefined index: st_tbl_id in 2 times.

Comment: Dude, You above query is showing 2 error which is Undefined index: st_tbl_id  and showing duplicate lg_name.