# Remove duplicate data from query results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
 select 
    C.ClientID,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName as ClientName,
    CAST(V.StartDate as date) as VisitDate,
    count(*) as 'Number of Visits'
 from
    Visit V
 Inner Join Client C on
    V.ClientID = C.ClientID
 group by 
    C.ClientID,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName,
    CAST(V.StartDate as date)
 having
    count(*) > 3
 order by
    C.ClientID, 
    CAST(V.StartDate as date)
```

which gives the following results (names are fake in case anyone is wondering)

```
 ClientID   ClientName            VisitDate      Number of Visits
 75         Kay Taylor            2016-06-07     4
 372         Moses Mcgowan       2016-09-03      4
 422         Raven Mckay         2016-03-11      4
 422         Raven Mckay         2016-06-14      4
 679         Ulysses Booker      2016-01-09      4
 696         Timon Turner        2016-07-06      4
 1063        Quyn Wall           2016-06-25      4
 1142        Garth Moran         2016-11-20      4
 1142        Garth Moran         2016-11-21      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-07      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-17      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-21      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-27      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-28      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-30      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-02-27      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-03-26      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-04-06      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-04-09      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-04-22      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-05-06      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-05-26      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-06-02      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-07-14      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-07-29      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-08-09      7
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-09-01      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-09-23      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-12-07      4
 1636        Kiara Lowery        2016-01-12      4
 2917        Cynthia Carr        2016-06-21      4
 2917        Cynthia Carr        2016-10-21      4
 3219        Alan Monroe         2016-01-02      4
 3219        Alan Monroe         016-02-27       4
 3219        Alan Monroe         2016-09-01      5
 4288        Natalie Mitchell    2016-03-19      4
```

How can I get the results to show only the ClientID and ClientName once so the results are like this?

```
 ClientID   ClientName            VisitDate      Number of Visits
 75         Kay Taylor            2016-06-07     4
 372         Moses Mcgowan       2016-09-03      4
 422         Raven Mckay         2016-03-11      4
                                 2016-06-14      4
 679         Ulysses Booker      2016-01-09      4
 696         Timon Turner        2016-07-06      4
 1063        Quyn Wall           2016-06-25      4
 1142        Garth Moran         2016-11-20      4
                                 2016-11-21      4
 1563        Hedley Gutierrez    2016-01-07      4
                                 2016-01-17      4
                                 2016-01-21      4
                                 2016-01-27      4
                                 2016-01-28      4
                                 2016-01-30      4
                                 2016-02-27      4
                                 2016-03-26      4
                                 2016-04-06      4
                                 2016-04-09      4
                                 2016-04-22      4
                                 2016-05-06      4
                                 2016-05-26      4
                                 2016-06-02      4
                                 2016-07-14      4
                                 2016-07-29      4
                                 2016-08-09      7
                                 2016-09-01      4
                                 2016-09-23      4
                                 2016-12-07      4
 1636        Kiara Lowery        2016-01-12      4
 2917        Cynthia Carr        2016-06-21      4
                                 2016-10-21      4
 3219        Alan Monroe         2016-01-02      4
 3219                            016-02-27       4
                                 2016-09-01      5
 4288        Natalie Mitchell    2016-03-19      4
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sql for this

Comment: Do this in your application code.

Comment: I agree with HB, this is better handled at the presentation layer.  Reporting tools will do this automatically with the right setting.

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately this is a dataset that needs to go straight to an Excel spreadsheet so there's no reporting layer here and the results can be in the thousands so it can't be done manually.

Comment: @James you can use a pivot table in excel for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, what you want is not to remove duplicates, but not display them.

In order to do this you can use a `CASE` statement with `ROW_NUMBER()` and show the value on the 1st row and display either `NULL` or `''` on the `ELSE` branch (the other rows):

```
select 
   CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ClientID ORDER BY CAST(V.StartDate as date) ASC) = 1 
           THEN C.ClientID
       ELSE NULL
   END as ClientID,
   CASE 
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ClientID ORDER BY CAST(V.StartDate as date) ASC) = 1 
           THEN C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName
       ELSE NULL 
   END as ClientName,
   CAST(V.StartDate as date) as VisitDate,
   count(*) as 'Number of Visits'
from
   Visit V
Inner Join Client C on
   V.ClientID = C.ClientID
group by 
   C.ClientID,
   C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName,
   CAST(V.StartDate as date)
having
   count(*) > 3
order by
   C.ClientID, 
   CAST(V.StartDate as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ClientId NVARCHAR(5), ClientName NVARCHAR(6), VisitDate DATE, NumOfVisits INT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('75' , 'A_NAME' , '2016-06-07' , '4' ),('372' , 'B_NAME' , '2016-09-03' , '4' ),
  ('422' , 'C_NAME' , '2016-03-11' , '4' ),('500' , 'D_NAME' , '2016-03-15' , '4'),
  ('500' , 'D_NAME' , '2016-03-19' , '4' ),('500' , 'D_NAME' , '2016-03-20' , '4'),
  ('500' , 'D_NAME' , '2016-07-15' , '4' ),('500' , 'D_NAME' , '2016-09-13' , '4'),
  ('600' , 'E_NAME' , '2016-03-19' , '4' ),('600' , 'E_NAME' , '2016-03-20' , '4'),
  ('600' , 'E_NAME' , '2016-07-15' , '4' ),('600' , 'E_NAME' , '2016-09-13' , '4')

;WITH A AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY ClientID) row_id,* FROM (

                     -----------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM @Table --- replace this line with your query----
                     -----------------------------------------


) Main_Result ) SELECT ISNULL(BB.ClientID,'')ClientID,ISNULL(BB.ClientName,'')ClientName,AA.VisitDate,AA.NumOfVisits
FROM A AA LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM A BB WHERE BB.row_id=1) BB ON AA.ClientID = BB.ClientID AND AA.row_id =BB.row_id
             ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,AA.ClientID)
```

Hope this helps. :)

you can execute this directly to get sample result from sample data. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this with GROUP BY, grouping by (ClientID, VisitDate).

See the response 1097 here: [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Note: In your ORDER BY is not necessary to use `CAST(V.StartDate as date)` you can use VisitDate because it exists in your SELECT: `... CAST(V.StartDate as date) as VisitDate,`

EDIT:
Try this:

```
SELECT  
    C.ClientID,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName as ClientName,
    CAST(V.StartDate as date) as VisitDate,
    count(*) as 'Number of Visits'
 from
    Visit V
 Inner Join Client C on
    V.ClientID = C.ClientID
 group by 
    (C.ClientID, VisitDate)
 having
    count(*) > 3
 order by
    C.ClientID, 
    VisitDate
```

Comment: How's that going to help? Sorting on a varchar column can indeed lead to odd sortings, it depends what format the date is in. If you want to sort by date, casting to a date can make a difference.

Comment: This is not what is asked at all, the question is to show the name and id just for one record, and leave it empty for the other rows with the same name/id

Comment: Ok. Then i think you need to use string concatenation for the columns VisitDate and Number of Visits. After, you can split each value in different rows. See: [link]https://www.codeproject.com/articles/691102/string-aggregation-in-the-world-of-sql-server[/link] -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below query would do that.... :)

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 select top 100 percent
    cast(C.ClientID as nvarchar(255)) as ClientID,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName as ClientName,
    CAST(V.StartDate as date) as VisitDate,
    count(*) as 'Number of Visits',
    row_number() over (partition by C.ClientID,C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName  ORDER BY CAST(V.StartDate as date) ) as rw_num
 from
    Visit V
 Inner Join Client C on
    V.ClientID = C.ClientID
 group by 
    C.ClientID,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName,
    CAST(V.StartDate as date)
 having
    count(*) > 3
 order by
    min(C.ClientID), 
    min(CAST(V.StartDate as date))

)

select case 
       when rw_num<>1 then '' else  ClientID end as ClientID,
       case
       when rw_num<>1 then '' else  ClientName end as ClientName,
       VisitDate, [Number of Visits]
from CTE
```

**Result:**

[image]

**My test Data in my test tables:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use your initial query as a CTE or as subquery to replace #TMP_DATA. Below is how I would do this. Using a CASE with the LEAD function to determine if the data in ClientID and ClientName should be displayed:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CAST(LAG(T.ClientID,1,'') OVER (PARTITION BY T.ClientID ORDER BY T.ClientID,T.VisitDate) AS VARCHAR) = T.ClientID THEN '' ELSE CAST(T.ClientID AS VARCHAR) END AS ClientID,
CASE WHEN LAG(T.ClientName,1,'') OVER (PARTITION BY T.ClientID ORDER BY      T.ClientID,T.VisitDate) = T.ClientName THEN '' ELSE T.ClientName END ClientName,
T.VisitDate,
T.[Number of Visits]
FROM #TMP_DATA AS T
```

The result set is:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBfEn.png