# Sql group data by week date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`due_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `title`, `due_date`) VALUES (1,'name1','2017-02-02');
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `title`, `due_date`) VALUES (2,'name2','2017-06-01');
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `title`, `due_date`) VALUES (3,'name3','2017-02-27');
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `title`, `due_date`) VALUES (4,'name4','2017-03-10');
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `title`, `due_date`) VALUES (5,'name5','2016-06-09');
```

And I have php code for print my data:

```
$database = new Database();
$database->query("SELECT * from test");
$database->execute();
$arr = $database->resultset(); ?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>due_date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($arr as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I print all rows. 
I have due_date column, date format.
How can I group my data for three catagorees: this week, next week and other week ( depends from due_date) .
And do that my code print:

```
This week
id name  due_date
3  name3 2017-02-27
Next week
4  name4  2017-03-10
Other week
1 ...
2 ...
5 ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score -1):

You are asking about SQL Group, but this is not what you need. You just have to sort your query and then, in the loop, break the table as you need.

```
$database->query("SELECT * from test WHERE due_date >= NOW() ORDER BY due_date");
```

The WHERE clause will not show you the past tasks. Check if you need it or not.

Then in the FOREACH statement, you need to check always the current element with the last element you already parsed

```
$lastDiff = -1;
$current_week = date('W') ;
foreach ($arr as $row):
    array_map('htmlentities', $row);
    $currentWeek = date('W', strtotime($row['due_date']));
    $diff = $week - $current_week;
    if ($lastDiff != $diff && $lastDiff < 2):
        $lastDiff = $diff;
        ?><tr><td><?php echo week_name($diff) ?></td></tr>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr><?php
endforeach;
```

And fix the title separator with a custom function like the following one

```
function week_name($week)
{
    switch ($diff) {
        case 0:
        $name = 'This Week';
        break;
        case 1:
        $name = 'Next Week';
        break;
        default:
        $name = 'Future Weeks';
        break;
    }

    return $name;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work: I get `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in E:\xampp\htdocs\lab12\index.php on line 18
TITLE 4name42017-03-10
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in E:\xampp\htdocs\lab12\index.php on line 18
2name22017-06-01`

Comment: Please, check the third line of my code, I just changed it. Otherwise, show where the error is in the code.

Comment: Now I get: TITLE : 4 name4 2017-03-10 
TITLE : 2 name2 2017-06-01

It is not what I need
I need this week, next week, other week

Comment: I wrote you to fix the week title with a custom function. You also need this? In case, you have to fix the query too, because you need to filter the next 2 weeks due_date tasks.

Comment: Yes, I need it too. Can you help me? I'll be very grateful

Comment: Вроде сейчас как нужно!