# select donater with his max donation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Donaters table:

```
id,name,phone,address
```

And Donations table:

```
id,donater_id,donation_amount
```

what I want is to get all donaters with their max donation amount like this:

```
id,name,donation_amount
```

I have tried the following query to get the result.

```
select a.id,a.name,max(b.donation_amount) max_d 
from donaters a left join donations b on b.donater_id = a.id 
groub by a.id,a.name,max_d
```

However, it returns duplications.

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: i tried this::
select a.id,a.name,max(b.donation_amount) max_d
from donaters a
left join donations b
on b.donater_id = a.id
groub by  a.id,a.name,max_d

but it returns duplications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Dtrs.Id ,Dtrs.name,MAX_Donations.donation_amount from  
         Donaters Dtrs left join (
Select Dtrs.id Dtrs_id ,Max(Dons.donation_amount) donation_amount  from Donations Dons 
         inner join Donaters Dtrs on Dons.donater_id = Dtrs.id 
Group By Dtrs.id) Max_Donations on Max_Donation.Dtrs_id = Dtrs.id
```

[Here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: this is working, but i had to change the first inner join to left join to get those who haven't donated yet

Comment: @BecauseGeek yes for getting those people who don't donate anything yet you should use left join

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

```
  SELECT dr.id, dr.name, MAX(ds.donation_amount) as donation_amount
  FROM donaters dr
  JOIN donations ds On dr.id = ds.donater_id
  GROUP BY dr.id, dr.name
```

This solution will miss the donators who did not donated anything. If you need such donators use `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` function.

Comment: You're faster, I will delete my answer, yours is better :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine, a Basic left outer join on the basis of the id and then aggregate max function on donation_amount.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,max(donation_amount) from Donaters a
LEFT outer JOIN Donations b
ON a.id=b.id
group by a.id,a.name
```

Comment: The on clause is wrong, you should check donaters.id and donations.donation_amount

Comment: duplication if donater has donated twice this will return two records for him