# group by 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that includes 3 columns:

[image]

How can i get the makers who produce only one product type and more than one model?
The answer should output the maker and the type.

Thank you!

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING etc.

Comment: The answer is in the title?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

```
select maker, type
from your_table
where maker in
(    
    select maker
    from your_table
    group by maker
    having count(distinct type) = 1
       and count(distinct model) > 1
)
```

The inner select gets the makers and the outer select adds the type.

Comment: Thanks i believe that answers my question.

Comment: I read a lot about Group statement but i just couldn't get the nested select.

Comment: Then add the query you tried to your question. Also add the expected output and the problem or error you have with the query.