# Condensing Multiple Rows to a Single Summary Row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to MySQL and am in need of some help. I have a table where each row represents an item for an order. These items are located in a specific area, as seen below:

```
Order Number            Area
EEN0103944              305
EEN0103945              305
EEN0103945              305
EEN0103902              104
EEN0103902              111
EEN0103945              123
EEN0103945              005
EEN0103945              002
```

I'm trying to create a table in MySQL that condenses all the information into one row, making orders the primary key, like below:

```
Order Number             Area
EEN0103945               305
EEN0103945               104, 111, 123
EEN0103945               005, 002
```

Comment: Don't. This is a violation of First Normal Form (the absolute bare minimum of good database design) and will make your life so much harder.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Detailed answer to similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Take perfectly good, atomised data... and ruin it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `group_concat()` with the `distinct` option:

```
select order_number, group_concat(distinct area separator ', ') as areas
from t
group by order_number
```

Comment: ... but pull this as a resultset, Don't create database tables like this. This topic is covered in Chapter 2 (Jaywalking) of Bill Karwin's excellent book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming", available at Amazon and other fine booksellers. (I believe a peek at most of chapter 2 is available in the "look inside" feature on Amazon.)