# select max count after group by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with schema and data as follows

```
id,winner,season  
1, Chelsea, 2014 
2, Chelsea, 2014 
3, Chelsea, 2015 
4, Arsenal, 2014
```

.
.

and so on.

Basically, there is an entry in there for every match of every season.

I need to query and identify the team that won the maximum number of matches for each season.

I got till retrieving the maximum number of matches in each season but I am not able to retrieve the name of the team that had the maximum. Any leads?

```
with  t1 as
(select count(winner) as cnt, winner, season from matches group by winner,season)
select max(cnt),season from t1 group by season
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: how you want to handle ties? show both?

Comment: Group by on multiple columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: what mySql version are you using? +8 can use row_number

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2b4b3/2/0

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, i would like to show both. I am practicing on 8.0.11.

Comment: @user3409426 how does below work for you?

Comment: @DanielMarcus The query works! I m able to see the winner and season. Still figuring out how I can bring the count too with your query! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
select t2.*
from (
select season, max(totalwins) as totalwins from (
select season, winner, count(*) as totalwins
  from matches t
  group by season, winner
) s1 group by season) w join
(select season, winner, count(*) as totalwins
  from matches t
  group by season, winner
) t2 on t2.season = w.season and t2.totalwins = w.totalwins;
```

Result:

```
season  winner  totalwins
------  ------- ---------
2014    Chelsea 2
2015    Arsenal 1
2015    Chelsea 1
```

Comment: This one works! Thanks! Can this be achieved without joins too?

Comment: The other option would be to use `WITH` statements instead of joins, but MySQL does not support them as of version 5.x