# Is there a more idiomatic way to implement my 'check_count' method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is whether there is a simpler or more idiomatic way to implement the `check_count` method for my `Deposit` class?

Here's the (long) context. In my current project, I have the classes `LineItem`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: line_items
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  customer_id        :integer          not null
#  item_type_id       :integer          not null
#  amount_cents       :integer          not null
#  amount_currency    :string           not null
#  check_number       :string
#  lineable_type      :string 
#  lineable_id        :integer
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :lineable, polymorphic: true

  validates :lineable_type,
            :lineable_id,
            :customer_id,
            :item_type,
            :amount_cents,
            :amount_currency,
            presence: true

  validates :check_number, presence: true, if: :check?

  enum item_type: {
    check:  0,
    cash:   1
  }

  def check?; item_type == :check end

end
```

and `Deposit`:

```
class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :line_items,
            as: :lineable,
            dependent: :destroy

  def check_items
    line_items.where(item_type: LineItem.item_types['check'])
  end

  def check_count
    check_items.
      group_by(&:customer_id).
      transform_values{|v| v.map(&:check_number).uniq.count}.
      values.
      sum
  end

end
```

So, if in my `line_items` table, I have (omitting the irrelevant bits):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | customer_id | item_type_id | check_number | lineable_type | lineable_id |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1           | 0            | 9989         | 'Deposit'     | 1           |
| 2  | 1           | 0            | 9989         | 'Deposit'     | 1           |
| 3  | 2           | 0            | 9989         | 'Deposit'     | 1           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can do:

```
Deposit.find(1).check_count
 => 2
```

Which is the correct result.

That `check_count` method seems clunky to me. Am I missing some cleaner way of doing this?

I'm using rails 4.2.8 and ruby 2.5.1.

Comment: I don't think that there is better way, you can do it with sql though but it won't be prettier IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are summing all unique check numbers per customer.

You can do it by using `GROUP BY` feature of SQL. Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421441/2460416) of how to do double columns groupings.
So to get the same in ActiveRecord(AR) you can do something like this.

```
  def check_count
    check_items.group(:customer_id, :check_number).count.count
  end
```

**NOTE:** as you interested in a number of such groups we are calling `#count` 2 times.
On the first call, the AR relation will be called resulting with

```
check_items.group(:customer_id, :check_number).count #=> {[1, '9989'] => 2, [2, '9989'] => 1}
```

the second call to count will calculate the number of the groups

```
{[1, '9989'] => 2, [2, '9989'] => 1}.count # => 2
```

Comment: Wow! I knew there had to be a better way. I'm going to have to meditate on that for a while. Thank you so much.