# Group By and Order By for SQL query

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to generate a report that shows how many Expense Reports (ERs) and the total of those reports for each employee for FY18.  The result set I have now has several duplicate UIN numbers--which is the identifying ID number for employees.  There should only be one record for each UIN.  I was thinking it had to do with the Group By and Order By clauses, but not sure.  Can someone point out the problem area?  Here's the SQL:

```
select x.er_employee_number "UIN", 
       x.er_user_full_name, 
       x.er_user_location, 
       count(X.ER_DOCUMENT_ID) "Number of ERs", 
       sum(X.ER_TOTAL_EXPENSE) "ER Total"
from INFOR.ALER_EXPENSE_EXPORT_HEADER@TEMPROD x
where X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS like '4' 
  and X.ER_PURPOSE like 'Employee%'
  and NEW_TIME(X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS_DATETIME, 'GMT', 'CST') > to_date('1-Jul-2017')
  and NEW_TIME(X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS_DATETIME, 'GMT', 'CST') < to_date('30-Jun-2018')
group by x.er_employee_number,
         x.er_user_full_name,
         x.er_user_location,
         X.ER_DOCUMENT_ID,
         X.ER_TOTAL_EXPENSE;
```

Comment: I believe your problem is with your `group by` statement.  You should only `group by` fields not including in aggregate functions.  So in your case, `group by x.er_employee_number, x.er_user_full_name, x.er_user_location` should work if those all return distinct values.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems you know that when a `GROUP BY` clause is present in a query, any column in the select list must be in either:

- A - an aggregate function
- B - the `GROUP BY` list

You may not fully understand the behaviour of the `GROUP BY` clause when multiple columns are specified. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421441/8061994) explains it pretty well. Essentially, the query is creating groups wherein each record contains the same `x.er_employee_number, x.er_user_full_name, x.er_user_location, X.ER_DOCUMENT_ID, AND X.ER_TOTAL_EXPENSE`. This is likely what is causing your duplicates.

As is, you can remove `X.ER_DOCUMENT_ID` and `X.ER_TOTAL_EXPENSE` from the `GROUP BY` list, as they are already used in aggregate functions.

Perhaps adding a function like `MAX` to both `x.er_user_full_name` and `x.er_user_location`, and leaving only `x.er_employee_number` in the `GROUP BY` list will get you the results you need. Note that the `MAX` function will effectively do nothing, so long as both the `x.er_user_full_name` and `x.er_user_location` are unique and not null per each `x.er_employee_number` See below:

```
select x.er_employee_number "UIN", 
   MAX(x.er_user_full_name), 
   MAX(x.er_user_location), 
   count(X.ER_DOCUMENT_ID) "Number of ERs", 
   sum(X.ER_TOTAL_EXPENSE) "ER Total"
from INFOR.ALER_EXPENSE_EXPORT_HEADER@TEMPROD x
where X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS like '4' 
  and X.ER_PURPOSE like 'Employee%'
  and NEW_TIME(X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS_DATETIME, 'GMT', 'CST') > to_date('1-Jul-2017')
  and NEW_TIME(X.EXPORT_HDR_STATUS_DATETIME, 'GMT', 'CST') < to_date('30-Jun-2018')
group by x.er_employee_number
```