# How to group by two fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
listId | accountId | amount 
1        1           20
1        1           20
2        2           30
2        2           30
```

I need to `SUM(amount)` and group by `listId, accountId` to get result:

```
 listId | accountId | amount | 
 1        1           40
 2        2           60
```

But it does not work for me: `SUM(amount) ... GROUP BY listId, accountId`

My full query is:

```
select `account_transactions`.*, 
`enterprise_invoces`.*, 
ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount>0, AT_amount, 0))) AS debit, 
ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount<0, AT_amount, 0))) AS credit 
from `account_transactions` 
inner join `enterprise_invoces` 
on `enterprise_invoces`.`AC_id` = `account_transactions`.`AT_code` 

where `AT_createuser` = 15 and 
date(`AT_transactiondatetime`) >= 2019-04-11 and
date(`AT_transactiondatetime`) <= 2019-07-29 and 
`AC_code` >= 601 and
`AC_code` <= 761 
group by `enterprise_invoces`.`AC_id`, `account_transactions.AT_transactionficheno` 
order by `AT_transactiondatetime` desc
```

Comment: Post your complete query you have tryed.. Unless i mis something very obvious here the query `SELECT
   t.listId
 , t.accountId 
 , SUM(t.ammount) 
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY 
   t.listId
 , t.accountId` should give the expected results.. Which i assume you have tryed here?

Comment: You need to provide the full query and the result you get.

Comment: Okay, I will post full query

Comment: It does not work for me too, fails on `...` .

Comment: *"It does not work for me too, fails on ..."* i assume the `...` in the question is meant as BNF (Backus-Naur form) if that is the case you should not read it literal or use it like that.. @Serg

Comment: I have added full query

Comment: `account_transactions`.*, `enterprise_invoces`.* ipmlies all columns including aggregated. This definetly will fail. Explicitly list the cols needed.

Comment: I have read this answer, and got how does it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421441/8291684

Comment: Your sample data and query have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Also that is generally also not how you should use group by.. see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)  but MySQL 5.7.5+ supports a exception on the basic SQL 1992 rule which is called functionally dependent which might make your query valid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select query should not have other columns and should have only the columns mentioned in group by and also the column which needs to be aggregated. So the query should be like this below.

> select `enterprise_invoces`.`AC_id`, `account_transactions.AT_transactionficheno` , 
>   ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount>0, AT_amount, 0))) AS debit, 
>   ABS(SUM(IF(AT_amount<0, AT_amount, 0))) AS credit 
>   from `account_transactions` 
>   inner join `enterprise_invoces` 
>   on `enterprise_invoces`.`AC_id` = `account_transactions`.`AT_code` 
>   where `AT_createuser` = 15 and 
>   date(`AT_transactiondatetime`) >= 2019-04-11 and
>   date(`AT_transactiondatetime`) <= 2019-07-29 and 
>   `AC_code` >= 601 and
>   `AC_code` <= 761 
>   group by `enterprise_invoces`.`AC_id`, `account_transactions.AT_transactionficheno` 
>   order by `AT_transactiondatetime` desc