# SQL query to return a list of items including the records details, count and sum prices

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I am a complete newbie to sql,

I have an access database table that contains a list of car part items including fields - partnumber, price, description, barcode etc- this table is used to temporarily store the details of a sale. It is a legacy system that does not include a qty ie for multiple items they are duplicate records in this temporary table.

I am trying to produce an "invoice" output in which I need to have The quantity of items (ie counts of duplicate items) list their description and part number and hopefully total each group of duplicate entries prices.

I have tried statements along the lines of

```
select partnumber, count(partnumber) as qty,
      description, price, sum(price) as subtotal 
from tblregister
group by partnumber
```

I know my syntax is way out just after some pointers as to how I achieve what I am after

Comment: try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the other non-aggregated fields in your `select` clause to the `group by` clause, like so:

```
select partnumber, count(partnumber) as qty, description, price, sum(price) as subtotal FROM tblregister group by partnumber, description, price
```

Comment: Ok will try - I thought this was the cause of the "does not include specified expression in the aggregate function - thanks for the help- will report back

Comment: I thnk that nail has been solidly  driven home - legend effort. Have voted ,but new, so seems not to add to public listing.
Much appreciated.