# SQL Sum amount for column with unique values

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

*Update*

Realised I was doing it correctly. The reason why I had the issue was because I didn't realise my data for Col1 wasn't as expected, having some Col1 that associates with multiple Col0 (It was supposed to be Col1:Col0 1:1 relationship. That's why the confusion of it's not working as intended.

*Original Question*

I'm using SQL query to sum a column for total revenue of distinct values in one of the columns, and return a table with combining with other attributes.

Here's my table:

```
Col 0    Col1   Col2(unique)  Revenue
X        1      A             10
X        1      B             20
X        1      C             0
X        2      D             5
X        2      E             8
Y        3      F             3
Y        3      G             0
Y        3      H             50
```

Desired output:

```
Col0   Col1   Revenue
X      1      30
X      2      13
Y      3      53
```

I tried:

```
WITH
  rev_calc AS (
    SELECT
      Col0,
      Col1,
      Col2, ##this is for further steps to combine other tables for mapping after this
      SUM(Revenue) AS total_revenue, ##total rev by Col1
    FROM table_input
    GROUP BY Col1, Col0, Col2 ##Have to group by Col0 and Col2 too as it raised error because of 'list expression'
    )
SELECT DISTINCT 
  table2.mappedOfCol0,
  rev_calc.Col1,
  rev_calc.Col2,
  rev_calc.total_revenue,
FROM another_table AS table2
LEFT JOIN rev_calc
  ON rev_calc.Col0 = table2.mappedOfCol0
```

But getting actual output with multiple rows of revenues under a specific Col1.

For example, when i filter by Col1 = 1 in the output table, I get a list of different revenue amount still:

```
Col1   total_revenue
1      10
1      20
1      0
```

I thought the `GROUP BY` should have sum up the revenue by distinctly under Col1. What did I miss out here? I also tried querying first `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Col1....)` way but the sum(revenue) is producing a list of different revenue as well

Newbie to SQL here, appreciate if anyone can share any insights here. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: thanks Hasan, as mentioned in the question, I was trying to use GROUP BY, but my issue is that the output still gave me multiple revenue amount for Col1 even when I have queried with GROUP BY

Comment: @unacom your desired output will be shown by GMB answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per explanation you provided, I think your requirement is aggregate revenue of selective records that map with another table based on Col2 values. If that is the case then you may try following query.

```
WITH
    rev_calc AS (
        SELECT 
            distinct(Col2) as Col2
        From table_input
        LEFT JOIN another_table
            ON another_table.Col2 = table_input.Col2
    )
SELECT
      Col0,
      Col1,
      SUM(Revenue) AS total_revenue 
FROM table_input 
WHERE Col2 in (select Col2 from rev_calc)
GROUP BY Col0, Col1;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Nilesh! I followed exactly and realised both yours and GMB way works. The reason why I had the issue was because I didn't realise my data for Col1 wasn't as expected, having some Col1 that associates with multiple Col0 (It was supposed to be Col1:Col0 1:1 relationship. That's why the confusion of it's not working as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want aggregation?

```
select col0, col1, sum(revenue) as revenue
from mytable
group by col0, col1
```

I don't understand what you are trying to do with `col2` in the query. This produces the result you want for the data you showed, that contains a single table.

Comment: thanks @GMB! So I still need col2 in the end result to be used when combining with another. table. I need to refer to that i.e. understand For each Col0, the list of values of Col1 & Col2 associated with it. Yes I want the aggregation, but i don't understand why my aggregation won't work in my query. If I don't include the Col2 in my query, I won't be able to select them to produce in my output table when combining at the 2nd part of the query