# How do I include attribute in Entity Framework Group By result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

Let's say I have a table of locations with location ID and location name. And let's say I want to get the revenues for each location (in this simple scenario I might not even need `GroupBy` - but please assume that I do!)

```
var revenues = await _context.SaleTransaction.GroupBy(s => s.LocationId)
    .Select(x => new LocationDTO {
        LocationId = x.Key,
        LocationName = ??? 
        Revenues = x.Sum(i => i.Amount)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

I tried to cheat

```
LocationName = x.Select(i => i.Location.LocationName).First()
```

since all location names for this ID are the same. But EF can't translate `First()` unless I use `AsEnumerable()` and bring the whole sales table into application memory.

Or I can traverse the result the second time:

```
foreach(var revenue in revenues) {
    revenue.LocationName = _context.Location.Find(revenue.LocationId).LocationName;
}
```

Given that the number of locations is fixed (and relatively small), it *may be* the best approach. Still, neither going to DB for every location `O(n)` nor pulling the whole location list into memory doesn't sit well. Maybe there is a way to assign LocationName (and some other attributes) as part of GroupBy statement.

I am using EF Core 5; or if something is coming in EF Core 6 - that would work as well.

Comment: I think it's better to start the query from the location table instead of SaleTransaction

Comment: @SinaRiani OK. Care to explain why?

Comment: Please let me know, what is the relationship type between Location and SaleTransaction? "one to one" or "one to many"?

Comment: the relationship type between Location and SaleTransaction? Seriously? of course one-to-many

Comment: What might solve your problem is to group by id AND namesee also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1):

From what I can briefly see is that you need a linq join query in order to join the searches. With EF linq query it means those won't be loaded into memory until they are used so it would solve the problem with loading the whole table.

You could write something like:

```
var revenues = await _context.SaleTransactions.Join(_context.Locations, s => s.LocationId, l => l.Id, (s, l) => new {LocationId = s.LocationId, LocationName = l.LocationName, Revenues = s.Sum(i => i.Amount)});
```

I will link the whole fiddle with the mock of your possible model
https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGJmjj

Comment: No, join is definitely not the way to go. Navigation properties can (and should) be used.

Comment: I like it! I am skeptical to Join in EF- it frequently reflects bad design (I *have* navigation properties from SaleTransaction to Location); but in this case it might be the right approach. Let me play with it a little

Comment: @GertArnold In EF Core it is easy to include navigation properties (Especially in .net 5), you can include one more property of type Location and you will anyway have to hold its Id, either in one to may relation so i think it is not that much of an issue

Comment: What is not an issue? Using join while a nav property is available is an issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by more than one value. eg;

```cs
var revenues = await _context.SaleTransaction
    .GroupBy(s => new {
        s.LocationId, 
        s.Location.Name 
    })
    .Select(x => new LocationDTO {
        LocationId = x.Key.LocationId,
        LocationName = x.Key.Name,
        Revenues = x.Sum(i => i.Amount)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Though it seems like you are calculating a total per location, in which case you can build your query around locations instead.

```cs
var revenues = await _context.Location
    .Select(x => new LocationDTO {
        LocationId = x.Id,
        LocationName = x.Name,
        Revenues = x.SaleTransactions.Sum(i => i.Amount)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: My LINQ statement is much more complex; as I said in OP - I realize that with simplifications that I did, I didn't even need `GroupBy` - but trust me... i do ;) The first statement - imagine that there are a dozen attributes for location; some may be quite complex (e.g., address, manager, etc.). So, while I realize I can put all the "cabbage" into GroupBy statement - then I'd rather traverse the resultant list

Comment: You can select (or group by) an entire entity eg `.Select(x => new { x.Location, ... })`. Though you might need to explicitly load owned types. Perhaps you should ensure your example is more realistic then.

Answer (score 0):

```
var revenues = await _context.Location
.Select(x => new LocationDTO {
    LocationId = x.Id,
    LocationName = x.Name,
    Revenues = x.SaleTransactions.Sum(i => i.Amount)
}).ToListAsync();
```

there is example:
[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UF46A9)

Comment: Thanks. As I said, in this simple scenario I might not even need GroupBy - but please assume that I do!

Comment: try something like `LocationName = x.First().Location.LocationId`