# How to write safe SQL query on strict SQL Mode

Tags: mysql, database

I write query like this:

```
SELECT name, class, period FROM subject 
WHERE organization IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
GROUP BY class, period
```

But, it causing error like this:

> Error 1055: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bsi.subject.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I found solving from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns). But, I am not so sure it safe. I am database junior. Is it safe? There is another solution without changing the sql mode setting?

I also found this [solution](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/). If column `name` not necessary, just simply remove it. But, I consider to add it to reuseable code.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions? Maybe it should be `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` to get all the names?

Comment: Show sample data and the result you expect.

Comment: Hi @Elbo, from my personal experience it is better to not have queries where the number of nonaggregated columns in SELECT and GROUP BY differ. Depending on the settings over your database, you could end up with different results, and it also would be more confusing for anyone else who is reading your SQL.

Comment: I think you can use it like this : `SELECT name, class, period FROM subject WHERE (class, period) in ( select class,period from subject where organization IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) GROUP BY class, period) ;`

Comment: Imagine that 2 different `name` values matches the same `(class, period)` value. Server must return one row. What `name` value from 2 possible ones it must to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every column in the Select statements has to be in the `GROUP BY` or have aN [Aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT   name) As name, class, period 
FROM subject 
WHERE organization IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
GROUP BY class, period
```

this would add all names from one period and class as a comma seperated strntg