# MySQL count distinct values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, distinct

I need to count the distinct number of people who visit each restaurant location. Multiple visits by the same person to the same location should only be counted once.

Input:

```
location    visitor
-------------------
sydney      john
melbourne   john
melbourne   jane
melbourne   pete
sydney      paul
melbourne   jane
sydney      jake
sydney      john
sydney      john
melbourne   jake
sydney      john
```

Expected output:

```
location    count
-----------------
sydney      3
melbourne   4
```

I've tried to follow examples here [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns), nested SQL queries like this one

`select distinct location,count(*) as c from (select distinct location,distinct visitor from guests) group by location,visitor order by c desc`

and endless Googling with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by the location, but your DISTINCT is per visitor

```
select 
      location,
      count( DISTINCT visitor) as c
   from 
      guests
   group by 
      location
   order by 
      c desc
```

However, considering your SAMPLE data is not good.  It would be better having lookup tables like Locations which has an ID and Location, and a People table with ID and Name.  Then your Visits table would have a Location_ID and a Person_ID.

What if you had a
John Doe
John Smith.

By just having John is not truly distinct and would give a false answer.