# How to use Group_By() on multiple columns to sum the rest of the columns

Tags: r, dplyr

This is similar to [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns) but I'm not too sure how to apply it to my case.

Here is the head of my data
I would like to `group_by(Date, Participant Code)`, and then sum all the other columns.

```
head(all_ergo)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  Date       time_bike distance bike_calories   power `Participant Code` time_active time_total desk_ca…¹ total…²
  <date>         <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00613 AE1_01                     360        360      11.0    11.0
2 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00613 AE1_01                    1920       1920      58.6    58.6
3 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00613 AE1_01                    3480       3480     106.    106. 
4 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00613 AE1_01                    3540       3540     108.    108. 
5 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00580 AE1_01                     360        360      11.0    11.0
6 2022-04-12       120        0             0 0.00580 AE1_01                    1920       1920      58.6    58.6
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​desk_calories, ²​total_calories
```

Here I used a similar code, but I can't figure out how to expand it to grouping by 2 columns

```
Summary_PRE <- workday_PRE%>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(Axis1:Counter,sum))
Summary_PRE <- subset (Summary_PRE, select = -c(Axis1,Axis2,Axis3,VM))
```

Comment: Posting [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240025/need-the-sum-per-date-per-another-variable) is a sure way of irritating the very people you'd like to help you.

Comment: well they don't need to help me, I'm just trying to understand a function that is complicated for me. If people that help others are easily irritated by stuff like this, should they really be helping others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant think in any short code way, but maybe as a temp solution you can specify all the columns in the summarise, like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, `Participant Code`) %>%
  summarise(time_bike = sum(time_bike),
            distance = sum(distance),
            bike_calories = sum(bike_calories))
```

Comment: Currently trying this, seeing how it goes```all_ergo <- all_ergo %>% group_by(`Date`, `Participant Code`) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(time_bike:total_calories,sum))```

Comment: Participant Code is a single column title, not Participant and Code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
all_ergo <- all_ergo %>% group_by(`Date`, `Participant Code`) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(time_bike:total_calories,sum))
```