# Why is my count function not counting the values of artistid correctly

Tags: sql, database

Using the view ridge gallery as the database. I am trying to count how many times the `artist id` comes up and count it after joining with another table.

This is my code:

```
select artistid,datesold, count(artistid) 
  from tutorials.work w 
  join( 
     select workid, datesold
       from tutorials.trans t  
      where datesold is not null
      )t  
    on w.workid = t.workid  
group by artistid, datesold  
order by artistid;
```

however it seems to only count 1 except for twice where it counts 2

[image: Here is the image of the result]

I expected it to count up the number of time `artist id` repeated however its just 1's and 2 twice

Comment: Replace images with formatted sample data from both tables and also include desired output. No idea what "view ridge gallery" is so also tag the appropriate DBMS (ie, MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc). Guessing on what you expect to see with your output, but you can likely accomplish what you need with a windows function such as `select col1, col2, count(*) over (partition by artist) as total from...` if your DBMS supports it.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. We don't know what data you have, and what result you want.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved. (Like w.workid instead of just workid.)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to count the number of times each artistid appears in the joined result set, along with the datesold. However, the issue you're facing might be due to the grouping by datesold as well. If you want to count the occurrences of each artistid regardless of datesold, you should only group by artistid. Try this query:

```
SELECT w.artistid, COUNT(*) AS count_artist
FROM tutorials.work w
JOIN (
    SELECT workid, datesold
    FROM tutorials.trans t
    WHERE datesold IS NOT NULL
) t ON w.workid = t.workid
GROUP BY w.artistid
ORDER BY w.artistid;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. cannot understate how much this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your count isn't working because your grouping isn't correctly formulated. When you group by both ArtistID and DateSold, SQL will group all the rows in which *both these items are identical*. So, if you have two rows with the same ArtistID but a different DateSold, they will be counted separately. Rows are only grouped together and counted if **they are identical in all the columns you've grouped them by**.

If you want to count all identical ArtistIDs, you need to *only* group by ArtistID. I refer you to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), which explains the GROUP BY clause quite well (and succinctly), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421441/9214088), which treats a similar problem to yours and explains it better than myself.

Comment: thank you. i am very new to all this esp since i have gotten out of a 2 year gap in studies. thank you for being open and helping out.